# VM instance, different from page markup

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

Create by 2C 4G
The actual 1C 4G
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

At Google Cloud Platform, The performance of one virtual CPU is not equal to the one physical core.

More preciously, One virtual CPU == 1 hyper-thread == 1/2 physical core. Here a is similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967797/is-1-vcpu-on-google-compute-engine-basically-half-of-1-physical-cpu-core) at StackOverflow. Thus in your case, you could see 1 physical core as you have selected a machine with 2 vCPUs.

Comment: Thank  you very much!